# Can some one explain what this code is doing? what are all the special characters in sed doing?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, awk, sed

```
jsonval () {
temp=`echo $haystack | sed 's/\\\\\//\//g' | sed 's/[{}]//g' | awk -v k="text"    '     {n=split($0,a,","); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print a[i]}' | sed 's/\"\:\"/\|/g' | sed 's/[\,]/ /g' | sed '  s/\"//g' | grep -w $needle`
    echo ${temp##*|}
}

dev_key='xxxxxxxxxxxx'
zip_code='48446'
city='Lapeer'
state='MI'
red=$(tput setaf 1)
textreset=$(tput sgr0)

haystack=$(curl -Ls -X GET              http://api.wunderground.com/api/$dev_key/conditions/q/$state/$city.json)
needle='temperature_string'

temperature=$(jsonval $needle $haystack)

needle='weather'
current_condition=$(jsonval $needle $haystack)

echo -e '\n' $red $current_condition 'and' $temperature $textreset '\n'
```

this code is supposed to parse json weather data to terminal using a developer key to call the information.

This the full code, can someone explain what sed is doing, I know it supposed to act as a substitute method, but why are there so many slashes and special characters used?

Also what is the echo ${temp##*|} doing, all these special characters is making it hard for me to understand this code.

Comment: Run this kind of cmd with your own input and see... echo "a\\b" | sed 's/\\\\\//\//g'

http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-1

Comment: Second, it is not in good style and written mess, learn from it will direct you to wrong way.

Comment: what is the value of "$haystack"?. without this value it will be impossible to know what sed is doing to the string you will have to cut the codes up into piece, trying each piece to see their output.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this command try to parse [json](/questions/tagged/json) It's far to be a good idea, since there's some nice item in the toolbox. One of them is [jq](/questions/tagged/jq). It's good at formatting JSON outputs or retrieving items in complicated Data Source. Example :

**file.json**

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "tags": [
                "bash",
                "vim",
                "zsh"
            ],
            "owner": {
                "reputation": 178,
                "user_id": 22734,
                "user_type": "registered",
                "profile_image": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/25ee9a1b9f5a16feb1432882a9ef2f06?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG",
                "display_name": "Brad Parks",
                "link": "http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22734/brad-parks"
            },
            "is_answered": false,
            "view_count": 2,
            "answer_count": 0,
            "score": 0,
            "last_activity_date": 1417919326,
            "creation_date": 1417919326,
            "question_id": 171907,
            "link": "http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171907/use-netrw-or-nerdtree-in-zsh-bash-to-select-a-file-by-browsing",
            "title": "Use Netrw or Nerdtree in Zsh/Bash to select a file BY BROWSING?"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Output from searching owner's sub HASH** :
[image: output]

Don't reinvent the wheel badly ;)